# How to sort dropdownlist Currency List item that not related with database?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cultureinfo, dropdownlistfor

How to acecending sort the dropdownlist in currency list. Is need to datatable/dataview?

```
   For Each cultureInfo__1 As CultureInfo In CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
        Dim regionInfo As New RegionInfo(cultureInfo__1.LCID)
        If DrpCurrency.Items.FindByValue(regionInfo.ISOCurrencySymbol) Is Nothing Then
            DrpCurrency.Items.Add(New ListItem(regionInfo.ISOCurrencySymbol + "" + regionInfo.CurrencySymbol))

        End If
    Next
```

Here the output :

[image: curr.png]

Comment: Anything that you can enumerate over in a `For Each` loop, you can call `OrderBy` on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need a subset of data you need to build a list of currency symbols and sort that.

```
Dim currencyList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

For Each cultureInfo As CultureInfo In CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
    Dim regionInfo As RegionInfo = New RegionInfo(cultureInfo.LCID)
    If Not currencyList.Contains(regionInfo.ISOCurrencySymbol) Then
        currencyList.Add(regionInfo.ISOCurrencySymbol)
    End If        
Next

DropDownList1.DataSource = currencyList.OrderBy(Function(k) k)
DropDownList1.DataBind
```